# My host is wildly unstable. Recommendations for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I'm on my 4th host trying to get a basic install working, but its been nothing but nightmares.

I am currently on what is regarded by many as one of the best Magento hosts, Nexcess.  They advertise full Magento compatibility, but in the last 8 weeks, they have yet to prove it, and are now telling me things that I need to consult with you all on.

For 7 weeks they tried to get my 2.0.7 install to become stable, (super-simple install, 4 extensions, 200 products, 15000 customers, Luma template). Attempts at a empty install with no products, customers, orders, etc yielded same errors and issues.  So after 7 weeks of issues and errors I requested a new server.  They recommended I also update to 2.1, and all my problems are solved!

Nope.

I allowed them to install to 2.1 per their recommendation, and when completed all seemed fine.  I then attempted to reinstall my 4 extensions.  Each failed with the error:

`Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.`

I contacted my host, who informed me that none of my extensions were compatible with 2.1. and that's why I got the error.

I've contacted each Dev to confirm that their extension works with 2.1.  They all appear to.

EDIT  So now its been 8 weeks and here is where I stand.  My host suggested I go to 2.1.  But no extensions 'are compatible' (again, I confirmed this to be false with all devs) with 2.1.  So despite having no stability with 2.0.x, they suggested I go back to that if I want the extensions to work.  So my two options are 2.1 with no extensions, or a broken environment for 2.0.7, but 'with extensions.

I don't know where to turn.  Can anyone here recommend a host that is successfully hosting a Magento 2.1 site with robust stability?  Or am I asking too much, is Magento 2 too unstable still, have I migrated too soon?

Comment: `So after 7 weeks of issues and errors `  where are they? edit your question, and remove all this text and add more technical information like `issues and errors `

Comment: Well they aren't telling me exactly what the errors are, but they sure are fixing all of them without question, and in support terms that is absolute accepting responsibility for it.

Comment: Just 'php config' and 'whitelisting javascript functions' and tons of permissions issues.  Now I am being given two options:  2.1 with no extension capability, or 2.0.7 with a wildly unstable environment, that to date hasn't shown stability on a basic install with sample data.

Answer (score 2):

To be blunt: No amount of hosting will fix lack of experience or ability on your part. The host is responsible for providing a functional web environment. They are not responsible for ensuring your software and modifications actually work. A crashing server or bad PHP configuration would mean an unstable or poor host -- a broken Magento installation does not.

The composer error you note (*Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned*) is simply a warning message. It doesn't mean the process failed (it didn't), nor that anything is broken (it isn't, at least as a result of that error). Every Magento 2.x installation gets that message right now. Magento needs to update their composer dependencies. That's Magento's fault, not yours. But, again, it's not breaking anything.

As to your problems beyond that, you didn't provide any details, so there's not a whole lot I can say except to investigate each one individually. Could be core bugs, could be configuration issues, could be extension-related, could be something else.

Comment: You might serve yourself to read more thoroughly.  I can provide you all the communication from the host as to their PHP config issues, which have been responsible for 95% of this.  Which I stated pretty clearly.  To be blunt:  Per the composer error, as I stated but you didn't register because you didn't read thoroughly, did cause the action to fail.  And what I was seeking was not your opinion of facts you don't have, rather suggestions from those that have a host that can provide a stable environment for any version of Magento 2.

Comment: If you won't provide useful information to respond to, or listen to feedback from professionals, then I don't know what more to say to you. Good luck with your problems.

Comment: If you won't read thoroughly, or insult people without knowledge of what's going on, then you can't help anyone with anything.